# Sequelize insert data having one-to-one relationship

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js

Lets say I have two models `Users` and `Statistics`.
One-to-one relationship of these models looks like this:

```
Users.hasOne(Statistics, {
    foreignKey: {
        name: 'userId',
        unique: true,
        allowNull: true,
    },
    onDelete: 'CASCADE'
});
```

However, I do not understand how to insert data to the child table. I tried to do it like this, but it doesn't work( `Statistics` table field is empty) nor throws any errors.

```
Users
.build({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
    Statistics: {
        gamesWon: 10 // For example.
    }
},
{
    include: [ Statistics ]
})
.save()
.then(() => {
    res.render('./user/register', { success: true } );
})
.catch(sequelize.ValidationError, (err) => {
    res.send(err);
});
```

What a am I doing wrong? How do I properly insert data to `Statistics` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While setting up an association using `hasOne` method, it will add getter and setter as well as a createChild method to the parent class.

it will adds User instance methods 'getStatistics', 'setStatistics', and 'createStatistics'

To link Statistics to a user you will need to call the method

```
user.createStatistics({
        gamesWon: 10 
    })
```

For your case .

The full example should be :

```
Users
.create({
    username: req.body.username,
    email: req.body.email,
})
.then(user => {
user.createStatistics({gamesWon: 10 })
})
.catch(sequelize.ValidationError, (err) => {
    res.send(err);
});
```